# Angular 2 Configurations in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I Have Gone through many websites but can't find any good to help me. As I am Planning to learn Angular 2 but facing problems in configuration.Tried many times but getting errors every time. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks In Advance

Comment: from Angular 2 docs [VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)

Comment: Thanks for The Reply but I have gone through this website earlier.....Np Ill try once again:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular2 with typescript then instead of Visual Studio use Visual Studio Code. It will come with intellisense for typescript.

Comment: Thanks @Megha .Ill Look After it